# Using the depth buffer instead of stencil buffer for clipping

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

On older iOS devices the stencil buffer isn't available. Also scissor only works for simple rectangles. For more general clipping can we use the depth buffer? To make things simple, lets assume that we are only drawing in 2D.

Also, my specific requirement is to be able to rotate the clipping rectangle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. E.g. (coded as I type):

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // to enable writing to the depth buffer
glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS);  // to ensure everything you draw passes
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);    // to allow writes to the depth buffer
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
                         // so that whatever we draw isn't actually visible

glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // for a fresh start

/* here: draw geometry to clip to the inside of, e.g. at z = -2 */

glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER); // so that the z test will actually be applied
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
                         // so that pixels are painted again...
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);  // ... but don't change the clip area

/* here: draw the geometry to clip inside the old shape at a z further than -2 */
```

So, key features are:

- the depth test can be set always to pass
- colour plotting can be disabled even while other buffer values are set

Comment: Don't we also need to do glDepthMask(GL_FALSE) after doing glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE)? So that the clipping area's depth buffer values don't change?

Comment: Oh, yes, that would make sense. For some reason I was thinking of (i) set a relevant clip area; (ii) draw an object; (iii) repeat. Which was a silly extra specialisation to imagine. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: @Tommy What about an arbitrary four sided clipping volume. I'm interested in a rotated and translated parallelepiped?